# Creating id with %in%

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create an id variable that identifies groups of numbers with the same id. That is everything that is in one row in idmat should be one id. If prod4 is one of those numbers, then the id should be the order of the row in idmat.

My problem is that I keep getting zeros for id. What am I doing wrong?

```
idmat<-matrix(c(1140,   1139,   1138,
             1146,  1145,   1144,
             1152,  1152,   1150,
             1159,  1158,   1157,
             1165,  1164,   1163), nrow=5,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)

prod4 <- c(1129, 1140, 1158, 1157)

# connect pairs:

pr4<- data.frame(prod4=prod4)
for (i in 1:5){
pr4<- within(pr4, { id <- ifelse(prod4 %in% idmat[i,], i, NA)})
}
```

Expected output: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the values of 'prod4', check if it is equal to 'idmat', get the row/column indices  using `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE`, then extract the row index  column (`[,1]`) and  create a `data.frame`

```
id <- unname(sapply(prod4, function(x) which(x == idmat, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1][1]))
data.frame(prod4, id)
#  prod4 id
#1  1129 NA
#2  1140  1
#3  1158  4
#4  1157  4
```

---

Or using a `for` loop

```
pr4$id <- NA_integer_
for(i in seq_len(nrow(pr4))) {
 pr4$id[i] <- which(pr4$prod4[i] == idmat, arr.ind = TRUE)[,1][1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option is to define your custom vectorized function `f`, but with the same core as [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60876696/12158757) did, i.e., `which`

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x) which(x==idmat,arr.ind = TRUE)[1])
df <- data.frame(prod4,id = f(prod4))
```

such that

```
> df
  prod4 id
1  1129 NA
2  1140  1
3  1158  4
4  1157  4
```